# How to right-align the text of menu items

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, right-align

I would like to right-align the text of menu items, I found a sparse solution, but it depends on the number of characters of each menu title (working with spaces):

```
 NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Text:             %12@",Text];
```

If there'd be another kind of class to use the menu item text instead of `NSString`, perhaps I could then use `paragraphStyle`.

Comment: What menu classes are you using? What should it look like (some left aligned and some right aligned)? Will justified work for you?

Comment: Thanks @Wain for your quick reply! I use statusItem NSStatusBar and if possible some left-aligned and some right-aligned as in two columns inside the menu text, one column left-aligned, and one right-aligned.

Comment: So you're using an `NSMenu`, or just status items?

Comment: @Wain just status items or better to say `[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar]`

Answer (score 2):

Both `NSMenuItem` and `NSStatusItem` allow you to `setView:` to provide a custom set of content. To this view you can add 2 labels, one left aligned and one right aligned (and whatever width you like).

Comment: Does that work with `[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar]` as well? I couldn't find any reference for `setView:` with NSStatusBar inside Apple's Documentation of it.

Comment: You are using `statusItemWithLength:` to get a status item?

Comment: Yes I am. Seems definitely like too much work, just for right-aligning the text.

Comment: Setting the view is generic, it's little different to setting the title, you just create a view and add a couple of labels to it, then set the text of those labels. It's all because you want 2 columns of text right?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want, but the columns would best be aligned in opposite order, so left column left-aligned, right-column right-aligned. I found example code online, but am skeptical as to the effort of rewriting everything.

Comment: Am not sure how to integrate that custom code, I have my statusItem set up correctly with all its functions and now adding a custom view, I would have to rewrite the whole thing, seems unfeasible to me.

Comment: You'd have to show more of your code. I assume at the moment you are just setting the title text with a custom string (using padding spaces in the middle)?

Comment: Yes I am setting the title that way, I wish I could somehow integrate it better with the sample code from Matt Gemmel: http://mattgemmell.com/files/source/nsstatusitemtest.zip But it seems far too complex of a task. But he uses a completely new view based on a rectangular view. I would use it if it was somehow possible to use my previous work combination of interface builder and classes and somehow make the code flow around.